# find and replace string with unique identifying string in multiple files

Tags: string

I'm working on a project where I'm to replace Lorem Ipsum with relevant text in web template files. Unfortunately, it's identical Lorem Ipsum text throughout all files, and the correlation between a screen and its generating template isn't easy to make. In other words, when I see "Lorem Ipsum ..." on a particular page, I don't have an easy way to tell which template generated it, even considering all other information on that page.

I want to replace all Lorem Ipsum over several files with a uniquely identifying string in all of the templates. Something like "Lorem Ipsum 1", "Lorem Ipsum randomStringHere" etc. That way, I can look at a page and grep to find the corresponding template.

I use this perl one-liner to find and replace in multiple files

```
perl -pi -w -e 's/SEARCH_FOR/REPLACE_WITH/g;' *.txt
```

But I don't know how to change it to do the uniquely identifying string. Hopefully something without too much development.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3873122/151841) like so:

```
find . -type f -exec perl -pi -e 's/ipsum/join "", map { ("a" .. "z", "A" .. "Z", 0 .. 9)[rand(62)] } 1 .. 64/eg' {} \;
```

and I get strings like `Lorem 1S1MWLSNys0eVhjVREMLRWaZFPSqPXy0bwjaXgXxluU8pajf4v6NbnPXjXTW5rdf`